# docker network not working with spring boot and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run spring boot and mysql through docker, but there is a problem that I cannot connect.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  docker-mysql:
    container_name: docker-mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - docker-mysql

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    container_name: app
    networks:
      - docker-mysql

networks:
  docker-mysql:
```

and spring boot application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306?
    username: root
    password: 1234
```

when i run it using docker compose, you will get an error that you cannot connect to the db.

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
..
...

Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: What's the actual error?  Can you reconfigure Spring to write out text-format logs rather than an image file, and replace the image in the question with the text of the error?

Comment: attached. Please forgive the fact that the log was cut because it was too long.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySql username in the docker-compose file is `user`, but in your Spring config, it's `root`.

Comment: `root` is an automatically created account. Even if you change to `user`, the same connection does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know this line is correct or not: `url: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306?`

Add this line at the end of your compose file:

```yaml
driver: bridge
```

So, your `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  docker-mysql:
    container_name: docker-mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - docker-mysql

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    container_name: app
    networks:
      - docker-mysql

networks:
  docker-mysql:
    driver: bridge
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver-1